# Can you call a vegetable plot "a vegetable bed"?

Tags: word-choice, american-english, terminology

Can you call a vegetable plot "a vegetable bed"? Or is this usage uncommon?

For example a bed of flowers is called a flowerbed.

Comment: [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=vegetable+bed%2C+vegetable+plot&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cvegetable%20bed%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cvegetable%20plot%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bvegetable%20plot%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BVegetable%20Plot%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BVEGETABLE%20PLOT%3B%2Cc0) shows both as in use, with "plot" used somewhat more frequently.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, you can call a vegetable plot "a vegetable bed", and this is not uncommon.

**bed**  [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bed)

> : a flat or level surface: such as a : a plot of ground prepared for
>   plants also : the plants grown in such a plot

as in:

- “The gardener planted a bed of roses”
- “The gardener planted a bed of flowers”
- “The gardener planted a bed of vegetables”
- "The gardener planted a bed of vegetables and ornamental flowers”

These are all correct, as bed means **a plot of ground in which plants are growing**.

Examples:

> - *Build Your Own Raised Flower/**Vegetable Bed***  [ThePioneerWoman](https://thepioneerwoman.com/life-and-style/build-your-own-raised-flowervegetable-bed/)

> - *How to Build A **Vegetable Bed** Biodynamically* [MotherEarth](https://www.motherearthnews.com/organic-gardening/how-to-build-a-vegetable-bed-biodynamically-part-2-zbcz1605)

> - Build a Raised **Vegetable Bed** [Denver Post](https://www.denverpost.com/2009/04/01/build-a-raised-vegetable-bed/)

Comment: So, in American English are plot and bed the same thing? Or is it the same as in Britain. (See what Chris H. says).

Comment: @Happy I'd say "bed" and "plot" are more or less interchangeable in most varieties of American English, except possibly "bed" is used more often for flowers and "plot" for vegetables. I think the term "garden" would probably be the closest US equivalent for Chris H.'s usage of "plot" (and "yard" would be our equivalent of the British "garden").

Comment: @1006a so wait, "yard" in American English means garden that is next to a house. And "garden" means any kind of garden, right?

Comment: @Happy For this American, a "yard" is a piece of land attached to a house. Usually there's a "front yard" and a "backyard" located in front of and behind the house, respectively. The yard (especially the front yard) may feature a "lawn", which is an area of trimmed grass. A "garden" is an area that is specifically cultivated for flowers or vegetables.

Comment: @Happy You can ask another question if you want clarity about that (or search the site; I'm pretty sure it's been discussed here before) but basically, "yard" is any land around a house, and "garden" is an intentionally planted/cultivated part of the yard, of any size.

Comment: @1006a oh, no, never mind, this I knew, thanks.

Comment: @Happy “Plot” would be unusual in UK usage. “Bed” is the normal term.

Comment: @MikeScott thank you. Well, I am learning American English anyways.

Comment: @Happy I wouldn't say plot and bed are necessarily the same thing. To me a bed is a smaller area entirely given over to cultivation. A footpath running through it wouldn't be part of a bed, and would likely split things into two beds. A plot can be larger, and could potentially include the footpaths. Also, a small field (e.g. 10x10 m) might be called a plot but wouldn't be called a bed. -- But all that might idiolect issues.

Comment: I think "plot" and "bed" are interchangeable in US English, but "garden" is not.  A garden implies a larger area that may contain multiple plots or beds.  E.g. *"In my garden, I have a decorative flower bed around the outside and beds for tomatoes, peppers, and carrots in the middle"*

Comment: It's rather confusing, at least in US usage.  You can have beds, but only for certain kinds of plants.  E.g. you'd speak of a flower bed or a strawberry bed, but not a potato or pea bed.  I think perhaps the distinction is whether it's a more or less permanent fixture or not.  Strawberries &c are perennial, but potatos & peas are replanted each year.

Comment: I've looked up "plot" in multiple dictionaries and it seems that plot = patch of land, not necessarily cultivated, whereas a garden or a bed always refers to something cultivated. So within a garden you might have several cucumber beds, comprising a cucumber plot and several cabbage beds, comprising a cabbage plot. If it's just one bed, then plot = bed, but bed is not always the same as plot (e.g. having a 20-bed cabbage plot you wouldn't call it a bed, because there are multiple beds in it).

Comment: @DarrelHoffman so, I think the relation is "bed -> plot", and not "bed <-> plot". Meaning they are not interchangeable, but you can call a bed a plot.

Comment: @jamesqf: Thanks for clarifying, always wondered what the distinction was. Could you post an answer?

Comment: @MikeScott "Plot" would sound unusual to this US speaker as well.  I'd also expect "bed" for a single small planting, and "garden" for a larger group of planted areas.  I suppose once we start talking about an area larger than I'd have around my house, I'd start talking about a field of vegetables (like at a farm).  Happy's assertion that "plot = patch of land, not necessarily cultivated" agrees with the usage I'm familiar with.

Comment: 'Plot' is generally staked out land; whether for a garden, mining claim, burial site, or even residential development.  So, as @Happy says, a bed (when talking about land, not sleeping) is a plot, but a plot is not necessarily a bed.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, you can, at least in UK usage. The [Royal Horticultural Society](https://schoolgardening.rhs.org.uk/resources/activity/potato-crop-sheet) refer to "vegetable beds" in their campaign for school gardening, for example.

They're not completely synonymous as you'll see from this description of my own garden: I have several [veg beds](https://www.quickcrop.co.uk/raised-beds), one [strawberry bed](https://www.theenglishgarden.co.uk/expert-advice/gardeners-tips/plant-strawberry-bed/), and two [herb beds](https://hartley-botanic.co.uk/magazine/make-a-herb-bed/). They're [island beds](https://www.rhs.org.uk/gardens/hyde-hall/hyde-hall-blogs/hyde-hall/January-2016/january-plant-of-the-month) separated by paths and together make up the vegetable plot. The examples I've linked (along with the more common "raised bed") demonstrate that phrases of this form are quite flexible

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it, your explanation is the most clear one!

Answer (score 2):

As a native British English speaker, I would call that a **vegetable patch**. Ngrams shows its [more common than 'plot' or 'bed'](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=vegetable+bed%2Cvegetable+plot%2Cvegetable+patch&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3).

'Vegetable bed' sounds wrong to me, [despite published usages](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/481618/143939). I would know what you meant but I wouldn't use it myself.

Comment: But vegetable patch is not always the same as vegetable bed, e.g. you would not call a patch comprised of 5 beds a bed. 

What you're referring to is like saying, "I just compared the words "head" and "leg" on google ngram and "leg" is more popular, so I will use that". :D

Comment: 'patch' is a synonym of 'plot': a small piece of ground marked out for gardening, and you've already accepted that 'plot' is fine. Your head/leg example is not the same.

Comment: When I was asking this question I thought that plot is the same as bed. But it turns out it is not.

Comment: You've accepted an answer which says "you can call a vegetable plot a vegetable bed"

Comment: In the question I call a vegetable plot a rectangular shaped, cultivated patch of soil that has no footpaths. Sorry, I should have been more clear.

Comment: So, basically my question was, "Does the phrase "vegetable bed" does natural?". I am happy that I was understood, heh.

Answer (score -1):

My impression, right or wrong, is that 'bed' is used only for small plots.
A large plot of a vegetable would be called a crop.
     For animals; chickens for example; if small, a chicken coop. If large, a chicken farm.

Comment: Hi Scott, welcome to EL&U. Note that this site is a bit different from other Q&A sites: an answer is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct* - preferably by quoting a reference (e.g. a dictionary definition) hyperlinked to the source. You can [edit] your post to add this detail; for further guidance, see [answer]. Make sure you also take the EL&U **[Tour]** :-)